# some images gets duplicated after the uploading - laravel

Tags: laravel

i am using a function that uploads multiple images and it was working perfectly locally but after deployment i am having this duplication issue .
i upload img1 and img2 and img3 but in the database i find only one of them like img1.jpg and the same thing in the folder .

```
public function _articleGalleryUpload(Request $request)
{
    $article = Blog::find($request->id);
    $img = $request->Otitle;
    //dd($img);

    $request->validate([
        'images'=> 'required',
        'images.*'=> 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:4000'
    ]);

    if(!File::isDirectory('assets/images/blogs/gallery/'.$img)){ 
        File::makeDirectory('assets/images/blogs/gallery/'.$img);
    }

    $images = $request->file('images');

    if($request->hasFile('images')) 
    {
    
    foreach( $images as $image )
    {
    //$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $ImageName = '_' . time() .'.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $image->move(('assets/images/blogs/gallery/'.$img), $ImageName);
    $imageP = Image::make($path)->resize(600, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });


    $galerie = new blogsGallery;
    $galerie->Img = $ImageName;
    $galerie->idart = $request->id;
    $galerie->alt = $img;

    $imageP->save();
    $galerie->save();
    

    }

    return back()->with('success', 'les images ont été téléchargées');

    }
}
```

i tried using array to store the names of the images but it didn't work, it uploads one image instead of multiple .

Answer (score 0):

Your code has one issue.
`$path = $image->move(('assets/images/blogs/gallery/'.$img), $ImageName);`

this code is error.
`$img` is one name for several images.

Comment: actually that's not right, $img is the name of the folder not the image

Comment: Oh. then you need to use old file name. Because laravel file storage move function require that. `Storage::move('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');`